# Data not displaying in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

Interesting predicament: Data for 'variant' is returned successfully, and for some reason it won't display in my cell's UILabel (the UILabel just appears empty, and yes, it's 'hooked up')? Is my currencyFormatter throwing this off somehow? Should I format this line differently? Help is appreciated.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *PointsTableIdentifier = @"PointsCell";

    PointsCell *cell = (PointsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PointsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PointsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


        BUYProduct *productsbuy = self.products[indexPath.row];
        cell.productLabel.text = productsbuy.title;

        BUYProduct *productDescription = self.products[indexPath.row];
        cell.productDescrip.text = productDescription.htmlDescription;


        BUYProduct *pointValues = self.products[indexPath.row];
        BUYProductVariant *variant = pointValues.variants.firstObject;
        cell.priceLabel.text = [self.currencyFormatter stringFromNumber: variant.price];

        NSLog(@"%@", variant.price);

    }


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: where are you displaying the label. Did you try to update the layout once set ?

Comment: @AkhileshSharma Just updated code. variant.price should appear in the priceLabel located in PointsCell. The other values (productsbuy.title & productDescription.htmlDescription) display in their labels just fine. Not sure why the variant.price isn't displaying...

Comment: All of the code inside the `if` statement (except for the 1st two lines) should be after the `if` statement.

Comment: are using autolayout for the label.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma Autolayout is on yes

Comment: @rmaddy Thks for letting me know, still doesn't fix issue though lol.

Comment: Did you apply the constraints on your nib? Seems to be the issue that your label is getting created but the size is not applied to it.

Comment: I fixed it! Changed cell label line to this and it did the trick: cell.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", variant.price];

Comment: That implies that you never initialized `self.currencyFormatter`.